# Divide/split a string on quotation marks

Tags: java, string, split, character

I have the following string:

I would "surely" like to "go to school".

Now, I would like to split this string at the ellipses, that is i would like to get the following output:

1. I would
2. surely
3. like to
4. go to school
5. .

Comment: What ellipsis? There’s none in your example string – did you perhaps mean quotation marks?

Comment: An ellipsis is three dots (…), generally used as a continuation mark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I case you meant quotation mark (`"`) instead of ellipsis, the easiest solution is to use **[`String.split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)**:

```
String text = "I would \"surely\" like to \"go to school\".";
String[] result = text.split("\"");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was quotation mark and that was exactly what i needed.

Thanks again.