# AS3 (string).split quotation mark only

Tags: string, actionscript-3, split

I want to split up a document by quotation it's marks. I see ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434348/divide-split-a-string-on-quotation-marks)) that they're able to fake this answer by adding a '\' at the beginning of the quotation mark, however in my document there are hundreds of these strings I'm trying to cut string out of, so changing that manually would be a real pain and time taker.

Here's an example of the string I'm trying to cut from:

```
<a href="http://www.awin1.com/awclick.php?mid=2194&id=1548" target="_blank">D</a>
```

And here's an example of my current code:

```
        private function onShopTextLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
        shopArrayOfWebsites = e.target.data.split(/\n/);

        for (var i:String in shopArrayOfWebsites)
        {
            trace("shopArrayOriginal: " + shopArrayOfWebsites[i]);
            var arrayString:String = shopArrayOfWebsites[i].split('"' /* << that won't work */ );
            trace(arrayString[1]);
            //shopArrayOfWebsites[i] = arrayString[1];
        }
    }

    private function postInShopView():void
    {
        var iLevel:Number = 1;
        var iSection:Number = 1;
        var iShop:Number = 0;

        for (var i:String in shopArrayOfWebsites)
        {
            iShop++;
            if(iShop >= 5)
            {
                iSection++;
                iShop = 0;
            }
            if(iSection >= 5)
            {
                iLevel++;
                iSection = 1;
            }

            var shopStringEquiv:String = "L" + iLevel.toString() + "S" + iSection.toString() + "Shop" + iShop.toString();

            if(global.shopTarget == shopStringEquiv)
            {
                var result:uint = ExternalInterface.call("showShopFrame", shopArrayOfWebsites[i]);
            }

            //trace(shopStringEquiv);
            //trace(shopArrayOfWebsites[i]);
        }
    }
```

I get an error of:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 1 not found on String and there is no default value.
```

So from here I'm not quite sure how I'm able to split up this document. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "split by quotation mark"?

Comment: Additionally you have an error in your code; `String.split` returns `Array`, not `String`

Comment: Why would it not work? It would... The correct answer lies above ^ from Pimgd. var arrayString:String should be simply var arrayString:Array. Because right now you are trying to trace arrayString[1] and a string instance does not have a property called "1". That's why you get the error.